# JavaScript: correct way to set object parameters with name and default value

Tags: javascript, function, object

What I'm trying to do is to pass an object to a function, where certain default values may be set, and the whole object shall have a name to pass it to another function.

The following code, without naming the parameter, works just fine.

```js
function test({
  item1,
  item2 = 0
}) {
  console.log(item1 + " " + item2);
}

test({
  item1: "foo"
});

function print(obj) {
  console.log(obj.item1 + " " + obj.item2);
}
```

But if I now start setting `obj = {...}` to pass to `print()` I get a syntax error:

```js
function test(obj = {
  item1,
  item2 = 0
}) {
  print(obj);
}

test({
  item1: "foo"
});

function print(obj) {
  console.log(obj.item1 + " " + obj.item2);
}
```

If I write `item2: 0`, there will be no error, but then in `print` `item2` is undefinded.

---

From the answers below, this seems to be the way that works best for me so far:

```js
function test(obj) {
  obj = Object.assign({
    item1: undefined,
    item2: 0
  }, obj);
  print(obj);
}

test({
  item1: "foo"
});

function print(obj) {
  console.log(obj.item1 + " " + obj.item2);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you're trying to call `print` that results in the error you describe?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Done

Answer (score 2):

Destructuring extracts properties from an object passed to the function and puts those properties into standalone variables - that's all. What you're trying to do is *mutate one of the parameters*, not *extract properties from the parameter into standalone variables*.

You can't mutate parameters inside a parameter list - for the sort of logic you're looking for, you'll have to do it inside the function body of `test`:

```js
function test(obj) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty('item2')) {
    obj.item2 = 0;
  }
  print(obj);
}

test({
  item1: "foo"
});

function print(obj) {
  console.log(obj.item1 + " " + obj.item2);
}
```

If you have lots of properties you want to assign default values to, you can use `Object.assign`:

```js
function test(obj) {
  const filledObj = Object.assign({
    item2: 0,
    item3: 'item3'
  }, obj);
  print(filledObj);
}

test({
  item1: "foo"
});

function print(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

If you only want an object with certain properties to pass to `print`, then extract those properties in the parameter list like you're doing originally, then pass a reconstructed object of only those properties to `print`:

```js
function test({
  item1,
  item2 = 0
}) {
  const obj = { item1, item2 };
  print(obj);
}

test({
  item1: "foo"
});

function print(obj) {
  console.log(obj.item1 + " " + obj.item2);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I see. But what if I want to provide the items of the input object inside `test`? Of course I could check if `obj.item2 === undefined` and manually set the default, but still that's not very beautiful.

Comment: What do you mean, provide the input items inside `test`? `=== undefined` may not be reliable enough, because the property *may exist* on the object, but have a value of `undefined`. If you want to make it prettier when you have lots of properties, you could use `Object.assign`, see edit

Comment: I mean I want to define the interface of test inside the function, to make clear which items the input object should prepare. I don't like to "blindly" access those items.

Comment: But `Object.assign` in fact is a nice way to do it

Comment: Then why not just use your original method, extracting the properties you want and assigning default values as needed, and then call `print` with a *new* object with those properties?

Comment: Only problem then is, that if I want to provide the whole interface inside the call of `Object.assign` I will have to set default values for every key.

Comment: If you only want certain properties, then follow your original method and create a new object, then pass it to `print`, as in edit

Comment: I just want to avoid to always pass `{item1, item2, ...}`, thus giving a name to the object suits me better, as I will have several calls inside test.

Comment: You only need to re-construct the object *once*, then you can pass it around to as many functions as you want. `print1(obj); print2(obj); print3(obj);`

Comment: Okay, I added another snipped to my question. From your answer, this seems to be the way that suits me best.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is invalid for assigning values in javascript, you are looking for `{key: value}`.

Change the `=` to `:` to fix the error:

```js
// You want to destructure you object, drop the `obj =`
function test({item1,item2 = 0}) {
  // If you were to modify this data, 
  // use `Object.assign({}, {item1,item2})` to prevent mutating your data
  print({item1,item2});
  
}

// save some space by destructuring the items you want
function print({item1, item2}) {
  console.log(`${item1} ${item2}`);
}

// Initial expected result
test({item1: "foo"});
```

**Object Destructuring vs Default Values**

I am assuming that you expect the value of `item2` to equal `0` correct? It does not equal `0` because you are passing in a new object that overrides the object in your function parameters.

Just like how if you were to set:

```
function(a = 1){}
```

and pass in a value, `a` will no longer equal `1` because it has been replaced with a new value.

The reason you get your expected behavior in your first code snippet (without having `obj = {...}`) is because you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) an object. This is not an assignment, rather, you are extracting pieces that you want from the object.

When you have a function with the arguments like:

```
function({arg1, arg2}){}
```

JavaScript will pull out these keys from an object you pass in.

**Assigning default values**

If, on the other hand, if you want to pass in an object without destructuring you may do it like so:

```
function(obj = {a: 'default'}){}
```

But, if you pass in an object in the function directly above, the default value for the object and all of its keys (`a` or any others) will be replaced with whatever object you pass in. [Here is a link on how default parameters work in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

I highly recommend you take a gander at destructuring, it is incredibly useful when dealing with objects or arrays in javascript.

Hope this helps,

Comment: In fact, as I've written above, it fixes the error, but `item2` then is undefined.

Comment: Yes, it should be, I've updated my answer to best explain why this is the correct behavior.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I get that. But it still doesn't solve my problem.